# How to plot paired data that has small deviations?

Tags: data-visualization, paired-data

I am showing that applying a certain method leads to improved performance on a machine learning problem, and that this effect is consistent across different datasets (in this case, datasets collected across different days).

However the effect is small (on the scale of 0.01), and when plotted out, is dwarfed by the large variation across the different datasets. Are there any alternative plots/visualization methods I can use to demonstrate my effect?

This seems to be a common problem when the effect is smaller than the variation between subjects/days.

[image]

Comment: A graph taller than wide might work better for you than one with your present aspect ratio.

Comment: @NickCox It's true! But changing the aspect ratio will only help you until a certain point, so I don't see it as a final solution

Comment: @David I don't know what would be a general solution (the phrase _final solution_ is better avoided; Google it to see why) without knowing the range of possibilities. Usually I would suggest log scale but the graph given doesn't encourage that idea.

Comment: Detail: showing 1.1(0.1)1.9 on the x axis is utterly pointless when data points are for 1 and 2 and intermediate values aren't defined.

Comment: @NickCox What about the idea in my answer?

Comment: Yes, actually making the graph narrower does help. Another idea I thought of is to just show the difference, thus reducing the data into one column. In this graph I will just show that most of the time, the points are below 0.

Comment: Which is already mentioned..

Comment: @David You're proposing a different graph.I can't speak for whether it would make it easier for the OP to think about their data.

Comment: @NickCox The question asks "Are there any alternative plots/visualization methods I can use to demonstrate my effect?" so I guess that's exactly what he's looking for

Comment: Indeed, but you asked what I thought about it. I can't manufacture opinions if I don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was doing a boxplot (or maybe a histogram) of the differences, but this is somehow incomplete as it loses information about the actual values (which I guess you do not want to happen)

However, what you may be interested in is a plot where you represent the variation (Y-axis) versus the value on the first day (X-axis). By representing it this way, you get rid of the "scale" problem